# nav drop down images - sub nav

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, dreamweaver, nav

At [this site](http://chesapeakerepair.missionmedia.net) when you hover over "service" tab you see a blue drop down, as well a yellow sub nav drop down.   The yellow sub nav drop down should not be showing as it needs to be hidden until user hovers over its parent "Repair."

Might anyone know what to add to the code to get this affect or have built something similar?

Comment: It looks like Dream Weaver is not putting a closing `</li>` tag after the nested '<ul>` menu.  Perhaps that would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `</li>` too much:

```
<li id="menuCellTop"><a href="index.cfm?page=menus&menu=full" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('repairs','','/images/repairs-active.gif',1)"><img src="images/repairs.gif" alt="repairs" name="repairs" /></a></li>
```

should be:

```
<li id="menuCellTop"><a href="index.cfm?page=menus&menu=full" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('repairs','','/images/repairs-active.gif',1)"><img src="images/repairs.gif" alt="repairs" name="repairs" /></a>
```

By the way, you have a lot of errors in your html, you might want to fix that to avoid things like this.